# Using R, Hyndman forecast package, and quantmod

Tags: r, quantmod

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I run the following code in R:

```
require(quantmod)
require(forecast)
getSymbols('FAGIX', from='2001-01-06', to=Sys.Date())
y <-Ad(FAGIX)
plot(forecast(y))
```

It seems to partially work but I get a warning message. In addition, the plot no longer shows dates. There's probably a simple solution here but I'm not seeing it.

Warning message:
In if (class(y) == "data.frame" | class(y) == "list" | class(y) ==  :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Answer (score 3):

The warning is because the class of an xts object is a two element character vector (`c("xts","zoo")`) and the `ets` function that's ultimately being called implicitly assumes the class of the object passed to it will only have a single element class.

Something like this might be a little more robust:

```
any(class(y) %in% c("data.frame","list","matrix","mts"))
```

Regardless, you can safely ignore the warning in this case, since the test is to check if the object is a univariate time series, which it is in your example.

Comment: But the plot no longer shows dates. If I plot "y", I see the dates in the x axis. If I plot forecast(y), I only get the index number.

Comment: `forecast(y)` doesn't return an xts object.  You would need to create an xts object from the output of `forecast(y)` or call `plot.xts` directly.